# How to access GPS location from the web browser

Tags: ruby, gps, geolocation

I am developing a mobile based web-application, in which I need to integrate Google maps. I need to fill `latLng` info from Google maps. Is it possible to get the GPS location and use it in my application?

Comment: better build in native mobile application

Comment: As users enters into the website , the browser in mobile should allow access to the GPS, that is my idea.

Comment: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocate/geolocate.html

Answer (score 3):

The browser is able to share the location with you thanks to *Geolocation API*, but you have to be aware of that, user when asked if he permits accessing the *geo-data*, might not agree. There is no way of *forcing* the locations to be shared with you.

Because it is part of Web browser API - there are JavaScript methods to be used.

The core of it is in very descriptive names of methods:

```
geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    console.log(position);
});
```

Check this [great tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-geolocation-api--cms-20071) of how to implement the solution on your own. It's really good, well explained and covers edge cases.

It covers much more code, so there is no point of copy-paste all of it here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad to help! Consider marking the answer as correct if it solved your problem - in case someone else is looking for help with similar problem, he can see this is the way to go. Cheers!